# MongoDB Transactions Write Conflicts

Tags: database, mongodb, concurrency

I have a value called x in my database and two transactions, T1 & T2. Assume both transactions use the multi-document ACID API MongoDB provides.

Each transaction reads the value of x and decrements it by 1. When reading, the code checks that the value of x is greater than 0.

Now, the value of x is 1 and T1 & T2 occur concurrently. Assume the following execution thread

```
T1 reads x = 1
T2 reads x = 1
T1 writes x = 0
T2 writes x = 0
```

In this situation will T2 detect that the value of x that it read has been changed and abort the transaction (presumably based on some internal timestamp) or will it continue with the write?

I have tried looking through the MongoDB docs and I can't find a satisfactory explanation to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following scenario:

```
transaction {
   read x
   if x>0 {
      write x
   }
}
```

Suppose one transaction starts and reads x=1, and the second transaction does the same and writes x. The first teansaction will fail and it will be retried. This tine it will read 0 and will not update.

That is why a transaction must include all operations that affects the transaction, and it must be retryable. If you read x before starting the transaction it would overwrite.

That said, this scenario can be implemented using an atomic update with a filter checking x>0.

Comment: Why would T1 fail even if T2 wrote first? Both of them read x=1 simultaneously. For T1, the if condition would still pass even if T2 committed because at the time T1 read x, it was still 1.

Comment: Afaik, a read operation will not lock.